# Package Automator Action for Mac App Store

Tags: cocoa, automator, mac-app-store

I want to sell my Cocoa Automator Action on the Mac App Store.

I see that some other developers sell a regular app that then will install the action into Automator. What would I need to do to get out of my sandbox and install the actions?

See this Action-installing app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/file-folder-automator-action/id479445983?mt=12

Answer (score 2):

No installation necessary -- Automator will find actions embedded in applications.  Just put them in MyApp.app/Contents/Library/Automator/, and the system should take care of the rest.

Comment: Is it still valid? Added action into this path and it doesn't look like system is care about it at all...

Comment: It should still work.  You mean it's not showing up in Automator?  In Terminal, run "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -dump", find your application, and look for the "library items" line.  If your actions aren't there, there's probably something wrong with the packaging.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! I found a problem, you need to install the app into the Applications folder. In this case, it's automatically added in the Automator library. Thanks and hope it'll help somebody.

Comment: Good to hear!  The application should (strictly speaking) not have to be in /Applications, but it does have to be registered with Launch Services.  Copying into /Applications is one way to do that, but launching it should also work.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Usually, actions are stored inside of an application and the actions are installed automatically into the "right place" when the application is installed.

I've read that sometimes you have to change the name of an application and then change it back to get its actions to install.

Here's a link about installing actions in general:
http://automator.us/developer-03.html

I guess that if a user just downloads your app that the actions might not get installed.  It would probably be best to have an installer made with PackageMaker.app to install your app, then, I imagine that the "right thing" would happen with the actions inside of your application when the application is installed.